# view custom connector activity

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I made a custom connector that is using the Graph API to return deleted groups.
I shared and app using this connector with our Service Desk, but looks like it doesn't work for them, it returns nothing. The connector is using a service account, so probably not a permission issue.

I would like to capture where the error is. Is it possible to somehow monitor the traffic that goes through the connector?

Answer (score 0):

@vilmarci, you could build some debugging into the Flow itself.

Consider:

- `Configure Run After` to alert you via `Notification` when the Custom Connector fails to run
- `Condition` that checks if Custom Connector response is empty and alerts you

There are all kinds of little "quirks" still in Flow.

You might also check:

- That the Help Desk is indeed using the correct Connection (the Service acct.) vs. their own AD Connection.
- If you've made a bunch of changes to a Flow, you may also consider recreating it from scratch. Sometimes this jogs the .json schema back into place.